# Get property from JSON object using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I know this has been asked before, but none of the syntax I've tried seems to work.

I have a standard appsettings.json I'm getting from a devops api call. It looks like this.

```
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I want to get the value of "DetailedErrors".

I have this as my powershell rest call.

```
$appSettings = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -ContentType application/json -Headers $header
$settings = (Get-Content $appSettings) -join '`n' | ConvertFrom-Json
Write-Host $settings.DetailedErrors
Write-Host $settings.'DetailedErrors'
```

...I've tried multiple times to either convert the object (or not), but both of the write-hosts print nothing to the screen.

Comment: Invoke-RestMethod already turns it into an object iirc. What does just running your first line and then $appsettings.detailederrors show?

Comment: $appSettings.DetailedErrors prints nothing using Write-Host.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access data from Invoke-RestMethod from Powershell API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792282/cant-access-data-from-invoke-restmethod-from-powershell-api)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this has been asked before by you here:

[Can't access data from Invoke-RestMethod from Powershell API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66792282/cant-access-data-from-invoke-restmethod-from-powershell-api/66797846#66797846)

I just responded to that post.