# Can't access data from Invoke-RestMethod from Powershell API

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I've tried everything I can think of here and I'm new to powershell and coming up blank. Hopefully someone can help.

I have a powershell call:

```
$appSettings = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header
```

If I log `$appSettings` to powerhsell IDE, I get:

```
PS H:\> $appSettings
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't access any of these properties.

```
PS H:\> $appSettings.DetailedErrors
```

Returns nothing...

```
PS H:\> ConvertTo-Json -InputObject $appSettings
"{\n  \"DetailedErrors\": true,\n  \"Logging\": {\n    \"LogLevel\": {\n      \"Default\": \"Trace\",\n   


PS H:\> $appSettings.'Logging'

PS H:\> $appSettings | Select -Property Logging

Logging
-------
```

So how do I get Logging.LogLevel.Default (meaning I want to know that it says "Trace")??

Update with full error log

```
PS H:\> $AppSettinsJson = $appsettings | ConvertFrom-Json
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid object passed in, ':' or '}' expected. (362): {
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "connectionStrings": {
    "Default": "Something"
  },
  "LockingTimeout": "60", //in seconds,
  "Major": "1",
  "Minor" :  "0",
  "buildDate": "#{buildDate}#",
}
At line:1 char:34
+ $AppSettinsJson = $appsettings | ConvertFrom-Json
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because of how you are trying to access it.

$appsettings is not what you want to work with. It is the JSON string $appsettings returned.

So, this...

```
$JsonData = @'
{
  "DetailedErrors": true,
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
'@ | ConvertFrom-Json

$JsonData.DetailedErrors
# Results
<#
True
#>


$JsonData.Logging
# Results
<#
LogLevel                                                                   
--------                                                                   
@{Default=Trace; Microsoft=Warning; Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime=Information}
#>

$JsonData.Logging.LogLevel
# Results
<#
Default Microsoft Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
------- --------- --------------------------
Trace   Warning   Information  
#>
```

So, if I refactor what you did. I'd do this:

```
$appSettings = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header) | ConvertFrom-Json

$appSettings.DetailedErrors
# Results
<#
True
#>


$appSettings.Logging
# Results
<#
LogLevel                                                                   
--------                                                                   
@{Default=Trace; Microsoft=Warning; Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime=Information}
#>

$appSettings.Logging.LogLevel
# Results
<#
Default Microsoft Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime
------- --------- --------------------------
Trace   Warning   Information  
#>
```

***Updated based on your response of PS version you are using***

The *Json cmdlets are only in PSv5 and higher.

```
# Results
ModuleType Name                         CmdletName_FinctionName             PowerShellVersion
---------- ----                         -----------------------             -----------------
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility ConvertTo-Json                      5.1              
Manifest   Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility ConvertFrom-Json                    5.1 
#>
```

Hence your errors.

If you are stuck with PSv2, then you could parse the JSON this way.

```
# Another approach in Windows 8 and higher
$jsonObjectClass = [Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject,Windows.Data.Json,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
($jsonObject     = $jsonObjectClass::Parse('{"data":["powershell","rocks"]}'))

$jsonObjectClass = [Windows.Data.Json.JsonObject,Windows.Data.Json,ContentType=WindowsRuntime]
($jsonObject     = $jsonObjectClass::Parse($JsonData))
```

***Update - you can also just save the string to a file, then hard parse the string.***

```
Clear-Host
((Get-Content -LiteralPath 'D:\Temp\appsettings.txt' | 
Select-String 'Default' -Context 0) -replace '\s+|\"|,' -split(':'))[1]
# Results
<#
Trace
#>
```

Comment: $appSettings = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Method Get -Headers $header) | ConvertFrom-Json throws a Invalid Object passed in ':' or '}' expected....

Comment: OK, then break it into two steps. Do your normal call to get the $appsettings populated, then do a second line. say `$AppSettinsJson = $appsettings | ConvertFromJson`.

Comment: It's powershell 2 in a devops build yml. I'm using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0 and getting appsettings.json, which I can tell it's returning as a string.

Comment: I've tried Out-String, Get-Content, -Raw all return some sort of error.

Comment: Wow, PSv2, really? That version is no longer supported, and really should be disabled as per MS recommendations. The *Json* cmdlets don't exist in PSv2.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops

Comment: On my local running (Get-Host).Version, it says I'm running 5.1 and still getting these errors.

Comment: @J.G.Sable, even if you break this into 2 steps?

Comment: Yes. I think I posted that.

Comment: I solved this. The answer was that there was improperly formatted comments in the json file. Once I cleared those out, $appSettings.Logging worked fine.

Comment: That was going to be my last, take. Not valid JSON.